# Post json file with Restsharp

Tags: c#, json, restsharp

I'm trying to send a json file with Restsharp

```
RestClient client = new RestClient("URL");

RestRequest requests = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
requests.AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------796538265423490134214350");

requests.AddFile("answer", "PATH");

IRestResponse responses = client.Execute(requests);
Console.WriteLine(responses.Content);
```

But its returning this error:

> {"code":"400","error":"invalid","message":"Invalid content. Body must contain a file with the answer"}

the API expects a file to be sent as multipart / form-data, as if it were sent by an HTML form, with a field of type file with the name answer

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: No, we don't know what specific information or structure this API is expecting in the body.

Comment: I know this is a backhanded comment, but please run your API through a localhost and debug your endpoints. Only then can you truly understand whats going wrong/right with you API and you can learn from it.